# What situations should $\oint$ be used?

Tags: calculus, integration, notation

Sometimes people put a circle through the integral symbol: $\oint$

What does this mean, and when should we use this integration symbol?

Comment: When you integrate over closed loops usually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This symbol is used to indicate a [line integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral) along a closed loop.
if the loop is the boundary of a compact region $\Omega$ we use also the symbol
$
\int_{\delta \Omega}
$

we can generalize such notation to the boundary of a region in an n-dimensional space and, if $\Omega$ is an orientable manifold we have the generalized [Stokes' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes'_theorem)
$$
\int_{\delta \Omega}\omega=\int_ \Omega d\omega
$$
that is a beautiful generalization of the fundamental theorem of calculus.