# Difference between $\int$ and $\oint$

Tags: calculus, contour-integration

If $C$ is a closed curve, what is the difference between
$$\int_Cf(z)\; dz\text{ and } \oint_Cf(z)\; dz?$$
For example why on Wikipedia [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) is

> For a holomorphic function $f$ and a closed contour $\gamma$:
> $$\int_\gamma f(z)\; dz=0 $$

and in the first line of proof is written
$$ \oint_\gamma f(z)\; dz?$$
If the both notations means the same, what notation is recommended?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I saw $\oint$ in math books (complex analysis) and also in physics books. But I saw $\int$ used for the similar things, and I am confused.

Comment: As far as I know there is no difference. The circle is just the indication that $C$ is closed. If you know that $C$ is closed there is no need to write circle in my opinion. Any way if some autor use $\oint$ in some nonstandard sens then there is his responsibility to meak this clear.

Comment: It's just notation, both mean the same thing. THe circle is just for extra emphasis that it's a closed curve (so the circle is actually redundant, but some people feel better if they see the circle).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303631 - - - - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4432338

Comment: @attdsp . It is recommended in mathematics to be as clear as possible. There is not always a notation that is clear in itself. If one author writes "closed contour" and uses $\int_\gamma$ and another prefers just to write $\oint_\gamma$ this is ultimately a matter of taste. I personally prefer a few words in the text more than less.